# Rstudio Server hangs when creating new Rmarkdown file

Tags: r-markdown, rstudio-server

I have trouble with running markdown on RStudio Server (1.4.1106) on CentOS7 offline server. When I click new->R Markdown..., R Markdown sign appears in the middle, and the program hangs. Same when I try to knit existing .Rmd document. I have to quit and restart rstudio-server. I have
R 3.5.1
knitr 1.22
rprojroot 1.3-2
rmarkdown 1.12
htmltools 0.5.2

Any help appreciated.

Comment: I installed the latest rstudio-server version hoping it would stop this behaviour, but no luck...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RStudio is trying to figure out if the `rmarkdown` package is installed, and it is probably hanging because it can't hit the Internet to see if a suitable version is available.

Does installing the `rmarkdown` package on your offline server fix the issue?

More info: https://github.com/rstudio/rstudio/issues/9246

Comment: I had an old version of rmarkdown and reinstalling the new version with dependencies almost helped - I got an error message to update xfun package and when I did, it worked!